# Unity Tweak Tool missing themes

Tags: unity, tweak

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Trying to change themes found only 4 they are Ambiance, Highcontrast, Paper and Radiance.
Looking in usr/share/themes I have 20 titles.
How to have Unity to see all of them.
Thank you